# Is OpenJDK used anywhere in the real world

Tags: java

### Edit:

English is not my native language. Maybe I am not expressing myself clearly enough. How about this:

The BCL for Oracle's JRE clearly states that the license is not applicable for java programs running on single purpose systems, such as TV set boxes or kiosks.
My guess is that there are some commercial kiosks and other types of single purpose systems that are running java programs, and I wonder what JRE's those programs are running on. I mean, statements like 'Amazon are using blablabla operating systems on their super big servers, with millions of users' makes me quite convinced that the blablabla OS is a good and reliable OS. In the same way, I would take comfort in hearing that 'Acme transport company are using IcedTea VM in are there ticket vending machines, and there are hundreds of them spread out all over the world'.

After searching and reading a lot, I am still having a hard time in understanding how well established the use of OpenJDK or some other completely free incarnation of the Java development kit and runtime really is.

Many developers do not seem to regard it a big issue if they run into problems compiling their software with OpenJDK, because they feel they can always switch to Oracle JDK/JRE if they have to.
But what if you really, really do want to build a commercial system based entirely upon free code?

Are there any critical systems out there that use nothing but IcedTea or whatever they are named, along with the usual bunch of third party libraries from Apache and others, that could help to convince me that using OpenJDK would *not* (edit) lead to a dead end?

Comment: Java is dead ... it's still used because where it's in use today it's too expensive to switch to other technologies, but many mission critical services like ebank services they use like the 1.4-1.5 version of Java. There are no reason to adopt Java, today, for a fresh and new business project, nevertheless Java is now a GPL project and Oracle has no interest and know-how to develop it in a good way, Java is dead.

Comment: I don't see the point of your question.  If you *"really, really do want to build a commercial system based entirely upon free code"* ... just do it.  There is nothing to stop you.

Comment: @user1849534 - Either you are trolling or you've been living under a rock for the last 2 years.  Or maybe both.

Comment: @user1849534 http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/history-of-java-is-dead.html ;)

Comment: How much are you paying for Oracle JDK, I am sure I get for you half price. ;) The Oracle JDK is based heavily on the OpenJDK and for the most part you are using exactly the same code, so the distinction isn't clear to me.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Oracle it's not developing java since years, the original JDK team it's not even working for Oracle anymore, there are dozens of languages better suited for every kind of task without relying on a super-bugged java VM, just take a look at the top-list for the JDK bugs.

Comment: @user1849534 Most of the Oracle developers working on the OpenJDK are the old JRocket team. IBM has now switched to developing the OpenJDK as well. You could say that a JVM which has Oracle value added version is dead as it's just a release of OpenJDK. While there are lots of good languages out there, Java is one of the most popular languages and most of the top languages are older than Java, not newer. I use latest versions of Java all the time and find about one obscure bug a year which isn't that buggy.

Comment: If you cannot use/run OpenJDK for anything in the way you want, it is not free software at all.